# Bitmoji for Slack says I don't have an avatar, but I do

Tags: slack

I set up Bitmoji in Slack, and I'm able to send Bitmoji with just my avatar with `/bitmoji command` commands. I can also send Bitmojis with someone else via `/bitmoji @someone command`. But if someone tries to do the latter with me, or I try to do it with myself, there's an error message `I do not have an avatar for your friend <name>`. Since I do have my account set up and have access to at least some functionality, I assume this is a misconfiguration of some sort. How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I too found the same issue on Slack for colleagues that have Bitmoji connected to Slack. I am not able to include them in group Bitmojis.

I was able to resolve the problem by changing the display name so that it does not contain and spaces or special characters. That seemed to work for a few people. However most recently this little trick has failed.

Comment: Changing your own display name?